# print blank line using JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtextpane

I'm sending html text to jtextpane, later I set attributes and use the print method, but when the print is too large the printer print a part of the text and leave a blank line between the text and later continue with the print

here's my method with the setting of attributes

```
public static void imprimirTicket(JTextPane resultadoTicket,int numeroImpresiones){
    try {
        for(int i=0;i<numeroImpresiones;i++){
        PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        attributes.add(new Copies(1));
        attributes.add(MediaTray.TOP);
        attributes.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
        attributes.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0, 10, 70, 2960, MediaPrintableArea.MM));
        resultadoTicket.print(null, null, true, null, attributes, true);
        }
    } catch (PrinterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Util.errorLogs("Error en metodo imprimirTicket de la clase Util.java error:" + e);
    } 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think your question is missing some punctuation...

Comment: what do you mean with punctuation, am I not explain myself??, the main problem is that the print is not showing complete, beacuse it appear a white line between the text I try to print.